# Can't see any resources referring to static arrays in C#

Tags: c#

Arrays in C#, including n-dimensional arrays and jagged ones, are all declared using new operator. Does it mean that C# only utilizes dynamic arrays?

P.S: by saying dynamic arrays, I mean arrays which are dynamically allocated, with their values in the heap and pointer referring to them in the stack.

Comment: Can you define what is a "dynamic array" to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, arrays in C# are usually dynamically allocated on the heap. All array types inherit from `System.Array`, which is a reference type.

Though, arrays can be allocated on the stack using the `stackalloc` keyword, which requires an unsafe context and is usually used for interoperability with native APIs etc.

Comment: Arrays can also be allocated on the stack using the `stackalloc` keyword

Comment: @KevinGosse missed that. fixed

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in c# are fixed size (I assume that by dynamic you mean dynamically resizeable). To create a "dynamic" collection, you could use `List<T>`. Under the covers, `List<T>` is backed by an array which is re-allocated and copied as the list grows.

The [new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator) operator is used because it represents that the runtime is allocating space for an object, in this case an [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.7.2) object. The new keyword is used for anything which is not a compile-time constant (I.E.  a hardcoded number, boolean, or string).